# How to execute Angular function from Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

For my Web-App I've created a html5 canvas and created functions that will allow me to draw on this canvas via mousedown, mouseup and mousemove:

```
<canvas 
    #canvas id="canvas" 
    (mousemove)="mouseMove($event)" 
    (mousedown)="mouseDown()" 
    (mouseup)="mouseUp()">
</canvas>
```

After testing I realized, that this doesn't work for touchscreens, I need a touchevent like so:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {

})
```

However I don't want to redo all code in Javascript and instead still use my Angular functions.. given this example, how do I execute the mousedown function from within the javascript function:

```
export class PenInputComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {

            // execute mousdeDown function here
        })
    }

    public mouseDown(): void {
        this.startDrawState();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this or is it even possible at all?

UPDATE: The solution is like follows:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    this.mouseX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
})
```

Since there are multiple touch events possible it's an array and one must get the coordinates accordingly but for angular you should put it into the canvas tag like described below.

Comment: you can use touchStart event? you have touch events.

Comment: Note that you don't really need the `public` keyword for methods; it should be public by default.

Comment: @Edric It's called typescript for a reason, so I type everything I can, makes my coding style look more uniform

Comment: @Miger Could you rephrase your comment? I don't understand.

Comment: @Miger It's called TypeScript because it has `type`s. Public is not a type, it is an access modifier. Or did you think it's called TypeScript because you have to type more than you would have to with JS? lol

Comment: I'm just trolling, the reason is, that I simply like to have the access anotated, I do this in every language.. and besides what is an "access modifier" .. well a type that tells you the access.. right :b  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(you can listen to any native HTML event from within angular templates, not just the mouse clicks)</sub>

You can use the [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerdown):

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas" 
   (pointermove)="mouseMove($event)" 
   (pointerdown)="mouseDown()" 
   (pointerup)="mouseUp()"></canvas>
```

This is not supported in Safari though. If you really want safari support you should use `(touchstart)` etc...

All in all, this is pretty basic angular with typescript material. I suggest you read in about both those subjects. Good place to start is the angular.io website.

To actually answer your question, you use `this.mouseDown` in your function, but then again, don't use `getElementById`, and `addEventListener` inside your angular application. So really.. don't use the code down here:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    this.mouseDown();
  })
}

public mouseDown(): void {
  this.startDrawState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What are those, what is a "pointer" supposed to represent?

Comment: I don't understand your answer.. using this.mouseDown() inside the JavaScript function doesn't work because it cannot access the function from within the Angular app.. I can use touchstart though.. Angular is a bit confusing because the intellisense will not suggest something like touchstart or sometimes simmilar things.. at one place I read that these touchevent are depricated anyway and we should use HammerJS instead.. I really don't get it??

Comment: @Miger I've updated my answer. Didn't realise you were using the `function` keyword. Don't do that, you will lose the `this` context. Always use the arrow notation. But still, just use the template event binding, and you can use hammerjs if you want, the template stays the same. Hammerjs is just for gestures

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there an easy way to test if the touch input actually works? it's not possible form me to test this on a touchscreen device, because I lack the authorisations to do this.. When I use the dev mode of google chrome the interactions still do not draw to the canvas but instead scroll the window around..

Comment: @Miger chrome devtools with mobile emulation is the way that should work. If that doesn't work, which is odd, you did a boo-boo :). Or you can try to add a `event.preventDefault()` in the pointerdown/touchstart listener

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Sadly I've tested both suggestions but none of them worked.. I'll do a little debuging and stuff. Even though it didn't work out for now you're answer is clearly correct and contains a lot of useful information - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just an Update: The problem was that I did not get the touch coordinates correctly, it should be like this:  this.mouseX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX

Comment: @Miger alright, that makes sense :) glad you figured it out!